# Best practice for converting ear to war file

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, ejb, war, ear

We are an IVR team and our application is deployed in tomcat server. We need to integrate with payment gateway.

We have a application enterprise web archive (ear) which has jar file and few other configuration files, this application communicates with third party Payment gateway. This application is provided by a vendor, As tomcat doesn't support ear files,

we want to know whether it is good to convert the ear file to war and deploy it in tomcat. The ear application provided to us is like a black box application.

We are trying to hit a EJB which archived in the ear

If it is right to convert ear to war, i would like to know the best practices so that we don't land on problem during production deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an EAR if you've got an EJB.  I don't see how you can simply change an EAR to a WAR and expect to access the EJB.

Tomcat is a servlet/JSP engine; it has no capability to host EJBs - unless you add on something like [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/).

Comment: When talking about application servers, it is possible to deploy EJBs within your WAR without the need of an EAR. But of course, Tomcat is a webserver. You need at least TomEE or something like this to promote Tomcat to some kind of application server.

Comment: Tomcat is an HTTP listener/servlet/JSP engine, nothing more.  You can't deploy EAR or EJB on Tomcat without making a modification, like your TomEE.  Personally, I have moved on from EJB to Spring Boot and microservices in the six years since I answered this question.  The rest of the world has, too.

Comment: lol... stumbled over this old question ... just for everybody who will, too... no need for an EAR with EJBs...